# Use specific flash player version in browser in cypress CI E2E

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I'm working with Cypress for E2E testing. I Wrote a test for a site that works with flash player 11.2 and above. My tests work fine and pass in my device browser but fail on CI because instead of expected page another page shows up that says you should use flash player 11.2 or above.
Can I set flash player version for chrome in cypress? If not can I install it? Or use Docker image?

Cypress:    `5.0.0`
Browser:    `Chrome 85`

[image]

Comment: which docker image are you using?

Comment: I'm using Azure pipelines `ubuntu-latest` vm